# QGIS Insufficient Permissions: Project File Not Writable

Tags: qgis

I have been working on some projects for a while now with layers and project files saved to the same external hard drive I've been using since the beginning. However, it has started giving me an "

> Insufficient Permissions: project file not writable

error message whenever I try to edit and save the layers/project itself (QGIS 3.10).

I have tried downloading an updated version of the software (QGIS 3.28), but I got the same error. This happens with both of my hard drives and all project files I've tried. I have also tried creating an entirely new project and saving it, but it says "

> Unable to Perform Zip

when trying to do that. It must be an issue with the project file or saving it to my hard drives. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you write to these drives from other programs? Copy files to these drives?